# How to display logs in json format in http-server

Tags: json, logging, npm, httpserver

I use http-server to run my vue.js application (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Is there a way to display standart logs in json format?

[image: Logs from http-server]

So the logs above will look something like this.

```
{"@timestap": "2019-07-18T10:58:28", "level": "INFO", "message": "Starting up http-server, serving ./puplic"}
{"@timestap": "2019-07-18T10:58:28", "level": "INFO", "message": "Avaliable on:"}
{"@timestap": "2019-07-18T10:58:28", "level": "INFO", "message": "   http://127:0.0.1:8080"}
```

Any help is appreciated, any hint to solve the problem will be helpful!

Comment: You may be able to use [rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/) which can output to many formats.

Comment: Yeah, but how to configure rsyslog with http-server?

Comment: That's a slightly different question - 'how do I configure rsyslog' you need to setup a template. have a look [here](https://techpunch.co.uk/development/how-to-shop-json-logs-via-rsyslog) it may help